# json reference extraction in python

Tags: python, json

Json is not only useful as a communication tool for APIs, but also may be used as a markup for configuring running programs as initialization.

I encountered the use of [references in json schema for the purpose of reuse](https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/structuring.html#reuse).

Since json schema is valid json, I had expected the python json library to have the ability to expand references.

```
$ cat test.json
{ 
  "template":{
    "a":"a",
    "b":"b",
    "pi":3.14
  },
  "value": { "$ref":"#/template"}
}
python -c "from json import load; fp = open(\"test.json\",\"r\"); print(load(fp))"
{'template': {'a': 'a', 'b': 'b', 'pi': 3.14}, 'value': {'$ref': '#/template'}}
```

What is the simplest way to expand the references in python, since python dicts cannot point to other parts of themselves (I think)?

Comment: What makes you think "python dicts cannot point to other parts of themselves"? Actually python dict values are just pointers, so you can have multiple keys pointing to the same value, and also cyclical references. This isn't really supported in standard json, though. I guess you are using some json superset?

Comment: Json references are indeed not in the standard, but an [expired Internet draft](https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-pbryan-zyp-json-ref-03). However, they are used in json-schema and swagger, which is where I came across them. @anton I don't know man. Maybe it was an unrealistic expectation to make. But I had a usecase for it - and it is nice when you find someone else has already solved the problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [json](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) library does not support references, but [jsonref](https://pypi.org/project/jsonref/) does.

`jsonref` is a library for automatic dereferencing of JSON Reference objects for Python (supporting Python 2.6+ and Python 3.3+).

From the docs:

```
from pprint import pprint
import jsonref

# An example json document
json_str = """{"real": [1, 2, 3, 4], "ref": {"$ref": "#/real"}}"""
data = jsonref.loads(json_str)
pprint(data)  # Reference is not evaluated until here
{'real': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'ref': [1, 2, 3, 4]}
```

Comment: I have to give it to you.. this is the perfect answer! :)

Comment: Note to people using this library, **it doesn't seem to be able to handle escaped characters in references** like `~1` for `/` characters. [I've raised an issue on their GitHub.](https://github.com/gazpachoking/jsonref/issues/33)

Answer (score 1):

thanks to @FreshD , who led me towards YAML which can be loaded and dumped just like JSON.

This is how I solved my use case, which was exact substitution to start with, but now also supports inheritance.

```
$ cat test.yaml 
template: &item
    a: a
    b: b
    pi: 3.14
exact-value: 
    *item
inherited-value:
    <<: *item
    a : I changed
$ python -c "from yaml import load; fp = open(\"test.yaml\",\"r\"); print(load(fp))"
{'template': {'a': 'a', 'b': 'b', 'pi': 3.14}, 'exact-value': {'a': 'a', 'b': 'b', 'pi': 3.14}, 'inherited-value': {'a': 'I changed', 'b': 'b', 'pi': 3.14}}
```

Comment: PyYAML's `load()` is documented to be potentially unsafe. If you use PyYAML use `safe_load()`. You should consider using my `ruamel.yaml`, it implements YAML 1.2 (PyYAML only does 1.1) and that is a superset of JSON, so it can load both. `python -c "from ruamel.yaml import YAML; print(YAML(typ='safe').load(open('test.yaml')))`. There is no need for escaped double quotes. Use single quotes within the command string.

Answer (score 0):

I never used/saw these references in json, but I know and used the in YAML also for configuration. [This](https://ahmedzbyr.github.io/python/var-sub-yaml-python/) is a nice description how to achieve this.

Comment: thanks for responding.. but your answer showed how to use variables. I didn't like the mixing of code/directives inside the data file.

but you did point me in the correct direction. https://blog.daemonl.com/2016/02/yaml.html

Comment: This page was the one I originally wanted to show you, but was not able to find it anymore. I also used this as reference.