# dereference JSON from muliple files

Tags: python, json

I am using python to dereference JSON from two/more files. 
Something like below,
content of file1 (Primary.json):

```
{
"$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
"$id": "https://hcmdevblobsa.blob.core.windows.net/order/v2/order.json",
"title": "LCBO order schema",
"description": "Canonical order structure describing various order types",
"definitions": {
    "addressDetail": {
        "description": "Address Information",
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
            "name": {
                "type": ["string","null"],
                "minLength": 1,
                "maxLength": 64
            },
                "age": {
                    "$ref": "secondary.json#/properties/age"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the File2(Secondary.json) :

```
{
"$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
"$id": "https://hcmdevblobsa.blob.core.windows.net/enumerations.json",
"title": "Enumerations used for JSON schemas",
"description": "Catalog of allowed values for schema properties",
"properties": {
"age": {
        "type": "integer"
    }
}
```

}

My idea is to use jsonref.I tried this library from the answer
[json reference extraction in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52870862/json-reference-extraction-in-python)

but in this case the reference is mentioned in the same file like this,

```
json_str = """{"real": [1, 2, 3, 4], "ref": {"$ref": "#/real"}}"""
data = jsonref.loads(json_str)
```

but in my case, the reference is in another file. So I tried to merge two files with jsonmerge and to use jsonref,
I tried using jsonmerge and jsonref with the below code,

```
import jsonmerge
import jsonref
import pprint
head = open('AltPrimary.json')
tail = open('Secondary.json')
result = jsonmerge.merge(head,tail)
final = jsonref.loads(data3)
```

this errors out in `jsonref.loads` because it doesn't know that the second part (after merging) is from 'Secondary.json'. So, it errors out while reading,

```
$ref": "secondary.json#/properties/age"
```

I tried by concatenating, 'seondary' to the file 'secondary.json' like,

```
"Secondary" :{
"$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
"$id": "https://hcmdevblobsa.blob.core.windows.net/enumerations.json",
"title": "Enumerations used for JSON schemas",
"description": "Catalog of allowed values for schema properties",
"properties": {
"age": {
        "type": "integer"
    }
}
```

}

but during validation it failed. In real world I may need to dereference from multiple files like below,

```
"person": {
  "$ref": "schemas/people/Bruce-Wayne.json"
},
"place": {
  "$ref": "schemas/places.yaml#/definitions/Gotham-City"
},
```

It would be helpful if anyone has any thoughts on this. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This library is not complete. It does not understand relative paths.
A workaround is to specify absolute path like this:

```
"person": {
  "$ref": "file:/root/schemas/people/Bruce-Wayne.json"
},
"place": {
  "$ref": "file:/root/schemas/places.json#/definitions/Gotham-City"
}
```

Or, you are welcome to create a PR.